# Flat ribbon network cables sold as UTP, are they really twisted, and how?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, twisted-pair

I am about to buy some network (Ethernet) cables for home use, and am looking at the flat ribbon variant as here:

[image]

However, given the very flat form and no visible structure that actually suggests some twist, I do **wonder whether and how these cables are UTP (unshielded twisted pair) or not.**

Here is [the full product link](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/maxxtro-netzwerkkabel-10m-black-utp-cat-5-ribbon-patch-cable-219245) in the online shop I was looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they [really are](http://www.vpi.us/cable-sf-shld.html). I have one such cable and it works well. Twenty meters of untwisted copper wires simply won't be able to work at 100Mbit/s.